# What about the results for ksvm?

Tags: r, kernel, svm

I've got the following code:

```
breast.svr=ksvm(Diagnosis~.,data=breast.train,kernel="rbfdot",C=4)
pred.svr=predict(breast.svr,newdata=breast.test)
tabel <- table(breast.test[,1],pred.svr)/nrow(breast.test)
tabel[1,2] + tabel[2,1]
```

The result is:

```
Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 

SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
 parameter : cost C = 4 

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  0.149121426557224 

Number of Support Vectors : 99 

Objective Function Value : -143.4679 
Training error : 0.028947
```

I know that I can extract a lot of information from this model on the following manner:

```
coef(breast.svr)
```

But I don't know what to do with it? How can I interpret this? How can I make from this a model like: f(x) = ...? More specific, how can I say which predictor variables that are important?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kernel SVM is by it's very nature not very intepretable. Each kernel uses many predictor variables so its hard to say which predictor variable is important. If you care about predictability, try to use linear regression or other interpretable models.